# How to get Alias Working in a Snowpack Svelte App

Tags: webpack, svelte, snowpack

I'm trying to compile Svelte Components in another folder and Snowpack can not find the path even with the alias in the snowpack.config.json file.

Any help on getting this working is appreciated!!!

Here is the snowpack.config.json file.

```
{
  "alias": {
    "components": "../../b5ui/src/components/b5ui"
  },
  "extends": "@snowpack/app-scripts-svelte",
  "plugins": [
    "@snowpack/plugin-webpack"
  ]
}
```

Imports in the .svelte file

```
<script>
  import B5input from "components/B5input.svelte"
  import B5check from "components/B5check.svelte"
  import B5button from "components/B5button.svelte"
</script>
```

npm start gives these errors...

```
[snowpack] [404] /_dist_/components/B5input.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5input.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5input.mjs
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5input.jsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5input.ts
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5input.tsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5input.svelte
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5input.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5input.mjs
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5input.jsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5input.ts
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5input.tsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5input.svelte
[snowpack] [404] /_dist_/components/B5check.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5check.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5check.mjs
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5check.jsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5check.ts
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5check.tsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5check.svelte
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5check.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5check.mjs
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5check.jsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5check.ts
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5check.tsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5check.svelte
[snowpack] [404] /_dist_/components/B5button.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5button.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5button.mjs
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5button.jsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5button.ts
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5button.tsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\public\_dist_\components\B5button.svelte
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5button.js
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5button.mjs
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5button.jsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5button.ts
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5button.tsx
  ✘ C:\Dev2020\psllc\imenu-sp\src\components\B5button.svelte
```